# How can I use v-model with an object inside a v-for loop in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Suppose I have this kind of objects

```
{
  [
    {id:1, name:'name1'},
    {id:2, name:'name2'}
  ]
}
```

Lets call the variable for this array of objects `names`. I want to use the whole object itself as the v-model value

How can I use the object directly as a value of v-model inside a v-for loop?
I tried something like this

I tried something like this

```
<div v-for="name in names">
  <input v-model="name">
</div>
```

But its ouputting something like this `[object Object]` inside an input field.

I want to dynamically change the value of this object when a user edit the specific input field with the specific object.

EDIT:

I tried using this approach
https://simonkollross.de/posts/vuejs-using-v-model-with-objects-for-custom-components

But when ever I type something on the input field it only copies the original value of the input field

Comment: Did you tried `v-model="name.name"`?

Comment: I mean i want to use the object itself as a v-model value not just the name inside the object.

Comment: @YvesGonzaga its not possible.

Comment: Do you want that user edit the whole object as a JSON string inside the text field? If not, the `name.name` should work. Anyways, the key is that you can use `:value` `@input` instead `v-model` and do whatever you want.

Comment: @The.Bear can you show how to use it with v-for loop? I tried using this an example of the creator of vue js https://jsfiddle.net/yyx990803/58kxs8tj/. But it seems not usable inside the loop?

Comment: @YvesGonzaga in the jsfiddle he's not updating a obj as v-model, he's just sharing the object to a child component with v-model directive, but inside child he is using `obj.value`. But question is, you only what to update the name property inside the object? That's really easy: https://jsfiddle.net/7wcvot3m/

Comment: @The.Bear your right I just realize it. I was always using it this way. I am overthinking things. I think its because of very stressful work this past days.. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Just link your data array directly

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      names: [
        { name: 'first' },
        { name: 'second' }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
{{ names }}

<div v-for="(name, i) in names">
    <div class="name">
        <input v-model="names[i].name">
    <div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be getting [Object Object] based on what you initially did. I don't think you can have an input model an array of objects.

To be clear, this is an array of objects:

```
let names = [
    {id:1, name:'name1'},
    {id:2, name:'name2'},
];
```

For the v-for, you should get the index just in case the id and index don't match at some point, and you should provide a key (which helpfully can just be in the index, or the id.

```
<div v-for="(name, i) in names" :key=name.id>
    <div class="name">
        <span>{{i}}</span><input v-model="name.name">
    <div>
</div>
```

That code will create a loop that spits out each name, prefixed with an index number. This will allow your user to change the underlying data of the "names" object.

You're going to get a lot of HTML if your names object is very big, but it's necessary to do what you're looking to do. The other options you can do is forget the v-for. Only show one input, and allow your user to manually increment through your object (with a "+" & "-" button or something) until they find the right name. From there, the v-model will once again enable them to mutate the "names" object.